# How can I write a strapi plugin that extends media library functionality?

Tags: typescript, plugins, strapi, media-library, cropper

I am facing a problem on the media library for strapi. For an upcoming project I would need to extend the cropping functionality of the strapi media library. Up until now it only seems to support free cropping but it would be nice if I could define one or two fixed formats for the cropping window like 4:3 or 16:9.

I already looked into plugin development for strapi and tried to find information on how I can extend the media library using plugins but so far I have not had any luck finding information about it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.